# Best way to reuse a dialog in WPF?

Tags: wpf, templates, dry, reusability

I have a WPF dialog with a couple user controls and some other standard controls. We have many uses for this dialog with specific tweaks. Right now this dialog manages all of the logic to tweak itself.

I can't help but think there's gotta be a better way. I wish I could do something like this:

Original dialog

```
<dialog>
   <Control1>
      <CustomHeader />
      <Control2 />
      <Etc />
   </Control1>
</dialog>
```

Dialog that varies slightly:

```
<dialog>
   <OriginalDialog>
      <CustomHeader>
         <TextBlock Text="The whole dialog will show and also include this text now" />
      </CustomHeader>
   <OriginalDialog>
</dialog>
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying for or even a better way that I'm not considering?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a `UserControl`.

Perhaps [this link](http://roecode.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/wpf-usercontrols-as-a-modal-like-dialog/) will help you out.

Comment: Or extend HeaderedContentControl. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.aspx